# Dot beetwen letters in word

Tags: php

Im trying to get PHP script that types dots beetwen letters in all possibles ways.
For example for `mouse` word it gives: `m.ouse, mo.use, ..., m.o.use, m.ou.se,...`

Please help me.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: At least show what you've tried before asking for help with homework.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through all the numbers from 0 to `pow(2,strlen($input)-1)`. For each one, treat it as binary. For each bit, if it is 1 there is a dot, and otherwise there is no dot.